# To get everyone's attention to newer / better answer

Tags: feature-request

This is more of a feedback than a question.

Once answer/answers get few upvotes, other answers are pretty much never looked at, and lose their chances to shine.

The recommendation I have is, any newly upvoted answer should be considered for higher order in the page. This would give newer solution a chance to get more looks and hence upvotes.

Comment: Not sure.  I've not really noticed that much.  When I've given a brief answer, and some other poster has given a more detailed answer, I usually manage to get a vote or two out of it.  The better answer gets more votes and accepted - fine!

Answer (score -13):

> To get everyone's attention to newer / better answer...

There's an informal (undocumented?) process that operates in the chat rooms. It consists of posting a link to a question or answer with a tag like [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) (close vote please). The tag triggers a mob vote at the behest of the requester.

I believe you can use the same tactics to generate votes for a question or answer. I'm told the process is useful and fair/balanced, so there should be a [uv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uv-pls) (up vote please) or similar. (I can't say for sure because I don't use the process or the chat rooms).

For a discussion of the process that runs in the chat rooms, see:

- [Close vote seeding in PHP chat getting out of hand?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256501/close-vote-seeding-in-php-chat-getting-out-of-hand)
- [Remove cv-pls tag from chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271899/remove-cv-pls-tag-from-chat-rooms)

Comment: Based on the number of downvotes on *this* question, it looks like the OP may have already tried the `uv-pls` approach ;)

Comment: Based on the number of downvotes on this answer, I think the community dislikes folks talking about their mob vote activities :)

Comment: Yes, the only acceptable incoming route for mob voting [is the Hot Questions list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta#comment81805_269211).