# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow, once again, is scheduled for an election [next week, July 17th](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation. Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352386/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

As we did [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're collecting questions one week in advance.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, July 17th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: All the best to the future candidates.

Comment: Also, please remember that these are questions for the candidates to answer, so please refrain from providing your own answers in the comments below them. We want the nominees to answer these later in their own words.

Comment: curious does the person who becomes a moderator need to be a CS nerd? I mean does the person need to know a little of like 7-8 languages? Can someone be a moderator without knowing nothing about C, C++? Because if the moderator doesn't know how can he/she know if a question needs to be closed, etc.

Comment: @Honey supposedly, they should only act when the community doesn't seems to be able to handle it itself. Exception handlers are for exceptional circumstances.

Comment: The last election wasn't that long ago, and I seem to remember it being said that those mods should be enough for a while. Has the mod workload increased this much? Are there any stats about the work being done by our existing mods? I'm partly asking because even though [we have 22 mods](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), some of them I only know because I saw them run in an election, or from that mod list. I'm not saying that someone whose actions aren't publicly visible can't be doing work, but are all those mods really doing that "at least 30 minutes work a day"?

Comment: In the past elections have been held because mods were stepping down, @AndrasDeak, but the retirement was not announced until afterwards.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - All I'll say is that [this is a significant factor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link). A sharp drop in reviews means that more flags are left for moderators to handle.

Comment: Pretty crazy to see the consequences of changing something like a navigation bar.

Comment: Will there be requirements about the reviewing that the candidates have done? I want to see candidates who have a history of diligent, high-quality reviewing.

Comment: @BradLarson Can we flag for mod questions that are IMO irrelevant to keep the list with only relevant questions - Asking what a future mod will do about when the actions to be taken are actually by the hand of the community ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351992/754119))

Comment: @AlonEitan - Unless the questions are wildly off-topic or (the opposite of what's normally true) not actual questions, I'd recommend using votes instead of flags. The whole point of voting on these is to determine what the community thinks are good questions for moderator candidates.

Comment: @BradLarson Great! Thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: Thank you to all candidates! You honor us with your service and hard work.

Comment: There are no candidates yet, @ScottCWilson; the election is next week.

Comment: How many moderator positions are we electing?

Comment: @ouflak from the [2017 Moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) page: _moderator positions available: 2_

Comment: Well, [unlike last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/337193#comment409366_337191), this year consistently doesn't show the hot meta posts.

Comment: "until Monday, July 17th at 20:00:00Z UTC" - shouldn't that be "until Monday, 17th July at 20:00:00Z UTC PM in the afternoon"?

Comment: Will the candidates be rejected if they give "incorrect" answers? (at least some of the questions below actually have what I would consider "correct" canonical answers, based on how moderation on SE works, including both tooling and rules). E.g. "Custom Flag" question has unambigous standard rule for migrations that every moderator candidate ought to be aware of.

Comment: this will be the first election held while i have been on the site, how do i participate?

Comment: @DVK: They probably won't be outright "rejected", but incorrect answers will absolutely result in less votes.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: have a look at the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) for some more information. I'm sorry to say you don't qualify due to the 3000+ rep restriction.

Comment: @Cerbrus can i not vote unless i have 3k?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Oh, I assumed you meant to nominate yourself. You can vote :)

Comment: @Cerbrus oh no, lol im far too inexperienced to nominate myself

Comment: @DVK there's no incorrect answers, just answers that doesn't follow the *status quo*. I prefer a moderator that doesn't follow the *status quo* but actually see the benefits/drawbacks of their actions.

Comment: @Braiam - I prefer someone who chooses best solution. And in some cases, "best" is rather objective and known (e.g. that answer I referenced about user asking to delete their question).

Comment: @DVK if you ask 10 people what is the best solution for a problem, you will get 11 answers. That's why benefits/drawbacks assessment is superior: it actually considers what would be the optimal solution for the problem. But I study economy, and we think everyone is rational.

Comment: @Braiam - if you ask 1000 people what the best solution under $5 for screwing in a philips screw using tools available at Home Depot is, 999 if not 1000 would point to philips screwdriver. Some questions really DO have "correct" answers. And the 1 person who would suggest using a hammer, ***I do not want around any building projects I would be anywhere near, ever***

Comment: @DVK and like that you did a assessment of the situation, not just blindly followed the *status quo*. Again, what I'm looking is someone that acts rationally, not another key smashing monkey.

Comment: @Braiam ;lkadsflkjaj;laljaslkjaslkjaskjllkjaslkasdljakjlasdflkjadslasj - damn my paws! :p

Comment: @JonClements Those are weird paws you have there...

Comment: @Braiam yeah... strange how they can hit mostly the home row of a qwerty keyboard. Calling me a freak are you because of my little paws, are you!? Let's go outside and sort this *mano a mano*.

Comment: @Braiam all joking aside though. A mod needs a sense of humour, some tolerance to what's thrown at 'em, and ultimately to be able to "step back" and review things in a rational way.

Comment: @Alex What does the Z stand for in the time? This hint was brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: is it possible to be a moderator with only 51 reputation? :))

Answer (score 143):

[Here's a classic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289454/19679) (happens pretty much every day):

> A question is asked and receives some very good answers. The asker then flags this question and asks for it to be deleted because having it up will cause them trouble at work or school. Do you delete the question?

Comment: @canon - Moderators aren't really presented with any guidelines after an election, aside from signing the privacy agreement and being told what user information we can and can't share publicly. Largely, you bring what you know and your own best judgment. There's a lot of grey area in the things you handle every day, so it's useful to see someone's thought process on these issues.

Comment: I understand that the company would not provide explicit guidelines for that, but I expect the moderators would come to a rough consensus among themselves, and that they'd teach new mods.  Do you really just leave the new people to learn the hard way?

Comment: I'm not saying that existing moderators don't help new people come up to speed on tools, procedures, etc., but there isn't a checklist you're presented with as a new moderator. Every situation you encounter is different, and you want someone who can judge the circumstances rather than blindly follow a flowchart. What's important about these questions isn't the exact answer, it's the thought process expressed in them.

Comment: @canon things that can be defined by policy/structure _generally_ don't need a human to intervene.

Comment: Surely they pick up all they need to know at the two-week induction course held in the Bahamas?

Answer (score 117):

Say you just performed a simple moderator action, like closing a question and leaving a comment explaining why.

The question's owner disagrees with your decision, flags your comment as "no longer needed" and replies with a comment that should be flagged as "rude or abusive".

Do you handle the situation yourself or do you wait for another mod to clean up?

If you handle it yourself, do you just dismiss their flag, delete their comment and move on or do take further action?

Comment: A very good question indeed. This is a common scenario with mods  especially when a mod answers a question and deletes an answer on the same question as NAA / VLQ

Answer (score 108):

Someone uses a custom flag to ask for a question to be migrated to another site. You're not a member of the target site. How do you decide whether or not to migrate the question?

Comment: Moderators, even from different sites, can contact each other, right?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro there's a chatroom for all moderators (Teachers Lounge), which yeah, allows you to contact any moderator team.

Answer (score 95):

Given a question that's closed as a duplicate of a fairly popular question (say a score of 10+, with multiple decent answers having a score of 5+), a gold tag badge user comes along, single-handedly reopens it and posts an answer that doesn't really differ that much from the ones in the duplicate.

The answer or question is flagged by a user who disagrees with the reopening, stating the answer merely duplicates content already present on the site.

What do you do?

Comment: This is the most topical, tricky question so far asked, I think. +10 for a very good sheep-from-goats question.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks. And no, I haven't experienced this exact scenario, just wondering how a moderator-to-be would react.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I can find an example or two of this case (even some 
 where the target duplicate is answered by the same gold badge owner) if you wish :)

Comment: There's an example of this happening (more or less) at [Swapping nodes in linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904628/swapping-nodes-in-linked-list).  The 'raise to moderator' step didn't happen; I didn't agree with the argument in favour of reopening, but decided not to contest it.

Comment: Why don't you ask if the moderator actually has any knowledge on the topic of the questions? Or better, why would you do that action.

Answer (score 82):

I've been a fan of this question that last couple elections.

> Do you have any Meta posts that you're particularly proud of, or that you feel best demonstrate your moderation style?

Answer (score 72):

A resubmit from [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337192/2607247), as this is always relevant:

> A user has been criticizing your moderation decisions on Meta. This has been occurring frequently over the course of a couple weeks. Some of these posts are very constructively made, with examples and reasoning, while some are more rants. While any mistakes you've made that have come to light were corrected when brought up, it seems that almost every day the user is finding something you've done to draw attention to.
>
> The user is a high rep user and generally does not cause trouble, but does seem to have an issue with your moderation style. How do you handle this situation?

Answer (score 55):

Moderators are expected to spend only 30 mins of their time, but we all know that 30 mins is insufficient. There are 2100 flags per day in the queue, a few of them needing 10~15 minutes. Most moderators spend way more than 30 mins and a few spend hours together. Would you be able to scale up your work time when the demand increases?

Comment: 30 minutes per moderator per day would be more than sufficient if every moderator actually spent 30 minutes per day handling flags. In practice, there are very few days where every moderator is active, and very few days where every moderator who *is* active spends 30 minutes handling flags - so a subset end up spending a lot *more* than 30 minutes to pick up the slack.

Comment: @Shog9 [thanks for the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1#comment491082_351972) ;)

Comment: @Shog9 Do you expect 30 minutes every single day, or 30 minutes per day on average?

Comment: Realistically, it should be considered an average, @Jeffrey - unless you're Bill the Lizard with 2967 consecutive days on the site, you're just not gonna *be here* to handle flags every single day. That said... I'd strongly encourage candidates to ask themselves if they can spare 3 hours a week (*beyond* what they already spend on SO), regardless of how that's distributed by day. If that sounds unlikely or even borderline, they might wanna re-think it.

Comment: @Shog9 Jesus christ 2967 consecutive days? That's impressive and scary at the same time

Comment: @mag, Bill was such a good mod that [even trolls used to respect him](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291712/4099593) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13DVy.png))

Comment: I had to vote this question down because it feels a bit like asking someone to work overtime in a day job without any additional pay. I know mods don't get paid, but suggesting they do more than the expected 30 mins is an unfair ask.

Comment: @DavidG Just to make myself clear, no CM/Employee/Mod will ever ask a mod to work harder. Infact if the queue is growing, CMs themselves take time out of their busy schedule and handle flags. Mods also get to take leaves for however long they want. What I've mentioned is only in the extreme cases where there's a sudden influx in flags. I just asked this to see if any of the candidate was willing to spend a few minutes extra to keep SO clean for all of us. (There was no other ulterior motive behind it).

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh I'm sure that was indeed your intention and that you're genuinely trying to be positive about it. However, I just want to make sure people understand the pressure that is created from even asking this question. Having performed lots of interviews for devs over the years, there's a few subjects I steer clear of and this is one of them.

Comment: @DavidG in my opinion this question should be at the forefront of any candidates mind. _If they are not willing to do the time, they should not bother being a mod_ as that places further stress on the other mods. I don't think it's unfair to ask. You know what you're getting into before you run.

Comment: @Bugs You miss my point I think. I agree that mods need to be able to commit the 30mins per day (or 3hours per week as per Shog's comment above) but I don't agree that they should be *expected* to do more. Now I'm sure that many/most actually do more of course, but that shouldn't be a job requirement.

Comment: @DavidG no I didn't miss your point exactly I just think we have different opinions. I think based on Shog's comment I believe this question is important. _If_ there are going to be times when more than 30 minutes is expected, the candidate should be prepared for that. It wouldn't make sense for a candidate to say _No, 30 mins is my max and I'm not going to do more than that, oh but when I'm on leave I expect everyone else to pick up the slack._ I think it's fair to say that all mods should help one another out and that sometimes _may_ end up requiring more than 30 minutes a day.

Comment: @Bugs Shog said users need to commit 3 hours/week above normal SO usage (which I take to meaning the general non-mod activity of answering questions etc.) so I really don't think it's important. Think of being asked this question in a job interview, very few candidates would answer in the negative. The point is that the job of a mod is 30 mins per day *minimum* and there should be no *expectation* of more than that. Those who do more are probably the majority and we thank them all for the extra load they take on, but I wouldn't exclude another mod candidate because they couldn't offer more.

Comment: @DavidG OK, I don't particularly want to get into a debate and take the focus away from the question at hand. I can see your point, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: wait - are you guys telling me that only moderators handle flags? That seems kind of...stupid? Especially with the work load present. Why can't people with...I don't know, 5k rep handle flag queues? [not talking about Triage/First post/First user here but flags like 'close this question']

Comment: @SteffenWinkler no, mods handle the special flags. NAA, VLQ and close flags are mostly handled by normal users (with 2k/3k+ rep) in the review queues... But then again, the throughput of those queues is low at the moment, so the mods may have to jump in.

Comment: @Floern yeah that's what I thought, was quite confused. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @DavidG If someone *can't* make that time commitment, why is it fair for them to take the position over someone who *can* make the commitment? If there weren't a limited amount of positions, it might make more sense.

Comment: @Rob So you're suggesting that we exclude people who can only dedicate 3-4 hours per week of time? Did your boss do the same to you at your job interview? We need to ask people to commit that basic time and if they choose to do more then that's great, but the question shouldn't be part of the interview process. This whole thing reminds me of [this boss](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/67/67851be4d08f9a4ffb3f0a48ef6e136eacae8e0fc0d0f7dfb9a53c36f388b097.jpg).

Comment: @DavidG You can't compare this and a job. The difference being that an employer has leverage over the employee in that the employee needs a job to survive. That's not the case here. If a volunteer is not able to put in enough time (which is being hinted at here, that 30mins/day is *not* enough) while others are; why should they take their spot?

Comment: Because we're choosing volunteers to mop up vomit. This kind of implicit pressure is unfair and unreasonable. If it's a 3 hr/week volunteer position, then, sure, if you can do more, that's great, but it should be an occasional bonus, not a "can you step up whenever it's **demanded**"? Frankly, I'd rather have a candidate who understands that this doesn't all ride on her back, and who can treat this position as professionally as she would a paid job.

Comment: @Rob You're right, this isn't a job, it's completely voluntary which means it should require *even less* commitment. Josh's comment just above this explains my point very well.

Answer (score 41):

Due to your status and actions as moderator and no matter how reasonable your conduct, you will be personally insulted more frequently, will have your competence questioned more publicly, and will be more exposed to negative sentiments.

How will you cope with this negative pressure long-term?

(Kendra already has an answer about handling a particularly abrasive/combative single user. This is asking more about the gradual pressure caused by many users acting more harshly.)

Comment: Bonus points for: provide a specific example of a time you handled it well, and a time you didn't handle it well.

Comment: This is *very* relevant. To illustrate, some related discussion from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283725/):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs88A.png (The feature requested there, anonymizing moderator messages, has been implemented in the meanwhile though, which is great.)

Answer (score 38):

To voters, from the comments:

> As a note, this answer isn't just referencing the great CEO incident. There have been other similar posts in the past year or so, which makes this an (in my mind) important topic

---

A controversial post has appeared on Meta. It is about how the site will handle some real-world, non-programming event. The community is torn between wanting the post left open because it is a major event, and wanting it closed as not pertaining to the site.

How do you help to moderate this conflict? How would your answer change if the post was instead an announcement from the team, which are also frequently closed and reopened several times?

Comment: Are you asking for the candidates to take a stand?

Comment: @rene only if it's on a flower pot.

Comment: @rene No, only how they would would moderate the situation. I'll reword to make that a bit more clear.

Comment: _Was_ the community torn?  I got the impression the community pretty heavily wanted that question closed, and only company fiat kept it open.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom that might be but let's not try to settle that under this answer. It is a good question for candidates to answer and a good chance to evaluate their responses given the real-life testcase we had.

Comment: @rene I guess I don't want to ask about "moderat[ing] this conflict", but more bluntly, "When the community disagrees with a company-made moderation decision, will you support the community or the company?"  But maybe that's too much of a leading question...

Comment: I don't know that a moderator has any discretion when the CEO wields the hammer...

Comment: As a note, this answer isn't _just_ referencing the great CEO incident. There have been other similar posts in the past year or so, which makes this an (in my mind) important topic.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Do you realize how much more quickly the company announcement in question was reopened than it was closed? And by regular users, almost never by moderator. I wonder how on earth you came to the conclusion most users wanted it closed.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Well, while it was happening I stayed out of it, figuring it would generate more heat than light, so my impression may indeed be wrong.  (I was sincerely asking.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom As a passive observer, I saw a lot of split on keeping it open and burning it with fire. I saw similar things with the other "political" posts that have been posted since the Great Logo Change. A number of users swears the post does not belong, another number swears that it does affect the site and therefore the post should remain...

Comment: This feels like a waste of a question given how rare this is and how few moderators even participate in the events. I get it might be important to you because of a post once or twice a year, but... I'd rather ask questions about topics that actually __matter__ in how SO works. Perhaps 0.1% or 0.01% of a moderator's time will involve issues related to this question.

Comment: Is this really something moderators should get involved in in the first place?

Comment: @enderland - If this was extended to all SE announcements (Documentation updates, community team initiatives, etc.) it's not too infrequent that moderators have to deal with heated arguments in Meta comments, combative answers that people have flagged, etc. How moderators act around those is an interesting question, because there isn't a clear-cut answer and existing moderators have even argued among ourselves about this. It's useful to pose questions that don't have an easy-to-look-up answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Well, elected mods *have* in the past gotten pretty heavily involved, so it's worth raising the question. Someone might take the position in their election platform that mods *shouldn't*, and that would be a valid opinion.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Almost never by a moderator? Take a look at the time line again, the majority of the reopens involved a moderator

Comment: @Rob Only 4 reopens involved an elected moderator, of which 2 were the 5th vote anyway, so it was the same as a regular vote. The rest of the diamond users are employees. The community also had no problem reopening it by itself, many times faster than closing.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for pointing out the announcements part! I've updated to add that angle to the question.

Comment: What was "the great CEO incident?"  This one? http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/man-accidentally-deletes-his-entire-company-with-one-line-of-bad-code-a6984256.html

Comment: @ScottCWilson The CEO of Stack Exchange, Joel, posted a post on Meta Stack Overflow that was.... Highly controversial. That's what I'm referencing.

Comment: Thanks Kendra. And I assume the post was taken down? Otherwise, please post a link.

Comment: @ScottCWilson I don't know if it was eventually or not, but I'll post a link if I find it

Comment: It's not the immigration post, is it? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand

Comment: @ScottCWilson That's it! Caused a lot of grief here on Meta.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the post was closed 30 times before it was ultimately locked for good. That's *one-hundred and fifty* >10k-rep users on Meta. Probably the most close-voted question on the SE network, ever. Of the 29 times it was reopened, 15 of those either included a moderator action as the last vote or were moderator-reopened using the mod power, including the very first reopening. You can bet a lot of the subsequent reopen votes were only cast because mods were reopening it rather than regular users. So to compare, that's 30 closures from normal users, and 14 reopens from normal users. ;-)

Comment: Either way, this is an interesting question that I'd love to hear some candidate responses on!

Comment: @Tyoer Meh. Even at the time, people who wanted it closed acknowledged the community mostly wanted to keep it open, because of how much faster it reopened without diamond users. The support is also reflected in the score, it is the second highest-scoring question on Meta SO. I also doubt people were reopening just because SE staff were.

Comment: `There have been other similar posts in the past year or so`: I don't really recall this? Perhaps on Meta Stack Exchange – like the recent net neutrality thing – but not Meta Stack Overflow? The only two occasions I can recall are the "Time to take a stand" question and the same-sex marriage logo change. Is this what you're referring to? Or something else?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There have been others, but they were questions by users and not the team. Naturally, they weren't _as_ major of a deal, since users posted them... But they still riled things up.

Comment: @TylerH nitty picky: I think the close votes are available at >3k. I voted on that question :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yeah, I was meaning to reference 10k as a function of how participatory they were in the site and therefore probably meta, not in a way germane to their ability to cast close votes, but then along the way forgot to discount the people who cast close votes below 10k. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

I'm reposting this [from last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337198/6535830):

> Not everyone agrees with every Stack Exchange policy, guideline, section of scope, etc. As a moderator, do you think you'll be able to effectively moderate and enforce Stack Overflow policies you may personally disagree with, but which the community strongly supports - or perhaps which you *and* the community disagree with?

Answer (score 32):

The review queues are always full; there are just not enough reviewers.

As it happens, a bunch of users are getting flagged for robo-reviewing or reviewing incorrectly otherwise <sup>1</sup>, enough to justify a review ban under normal circumstances.

Do you ban these users from review, even though that worsens the throughput of the review queues even more?

<sub>1: and are not caught by audits.</sub>

Comment: "a bunch of users are getting flagged for robo-reviewing" You mean erroneously? If so, [citation-needed]

Comment: @TylerH no, I mean for example a reviewer notices that another reviewer is reviewing inappropriately, and then raises a flag.

Answer (score 26):

Suppose there is a question in which the community (either via 5 voters or a dupe-hammer) closed the question as a duplicate.  After closing and a subsequent edit, the question has been through the reopen queue and most users voted to leave closed.

You then come across a custom flag, which essentially says

> My question was wrongly closed as a duplicate, please reopen it.

After looking at the flag and reviewing the question, you feel that the community's decision was completely wrong and the question is not a duplicate.  Since this question is in your area of expertise, you feel **very** qualified to make this judgement and you are very confident of your position here.

What do you do?

- Do you override the community's decision here even though it was closed and failed to make it through the reopen queue?
- Do you abide by the community's decision on this post?

I'm not necessarily referring to how you will handle the specific flag, but using it as an example of how you happened across the post.  The specific question is "what will do you?" and "would you reopen it".

---

To put this in more generic terms, how will you to address a community decisions when your expertise and experience suggest that the community decision was wrong.  Will you go against the community decision?

Answer (score 22):

1. If someone comes up with a comment like (especially with a new OP
   asking that doesn't have an informed badge):

   > Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (again), and get informed what and how you can ask here.

   And that comment is flagged as *unconstructive* a number of times.

   How do you act?

   1. Accept
   2. Decline
   3. Digging down the question context and judge for *off-topic* or not
2. If we deal with obvious *Do my homeworkz plz* questions, and someone leaves a comment like

   > What did you try so far?

   And that comment is flagged as *unconstructive* a number of times.

   How do you act?

   1. Accept
   2. Decline
   3. Digging down the question context and judge for *off-topic* or not

Comment: I WOULD HUNT DOWN THE FLAGGERS AND STOMP ON THEIR TOYS

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hunting voting rings and flagging mobs?

Comment: @Pekka웃 You get my vote

Answer (score 22):

Let’s make this one a tradition:

> How would you, as a moderator, deal with a situation where a group of users unanimously disagree with your ruling while you’re 100% sure you based your decision on the standing policy?
>
> What if your ruling was issued in a chatroom?

[mostly copied from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337193/5244995)

Comment: This copy is approved by me...

Answer (score 22):

Apparently a lot of the current moderators aren't spending the 30 minutes a day we elected them to do ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1#comment491101_351974)). Is there any reason to believe that you will actually spend the time?

Answer (score 21):

Here is a set of general questions, this time *actually* posted instead of mysteriously forgotten, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 20):

There's been some debate surrounding the [flagging of link-only answers as NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332607/why-were-these-two-naa-flags-declined-for-link-only-answers-one-of-these-being).

If someone flags a link-only answer as NAA, how do you handle this and why?

Answer (score 15):

You (as a mod) close a poor question that is asking for an off site resource. Then the person who posted that question on Stack Overflow contacts you on LinkedIn and says that you suck as a mod. He then becomes a little rude and says that you are too weak and cannot do anything to him.

How would you as a mod handle this situation?.

Comment: I imagine there's a story behind this one... o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus - Not really. This question is completely hypothetical. No such thing happened on March 18th, 11:23 PM UTC. :P

Comment: Please tell us what one might do in such hypothetical scenario, after the election

Comment: Accept the invite, add them in your contact list, endorse them for interpersonal skills and call it a day....

Comment: @AlonEitan Engage in an epic rap battle with them.

Comment: I believe this sort of abuse is something every Stack Overflow mod will have to deal with sooner or later :-( This is actually quite "mild" compared to some of the other stories I've heard.

Comment: @TheLostMind [500 Days of Summer disclaimer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1022603/crazycredits)

Comment: @Michael - Lol. That made my day :P

Answer (score 14):

You have just discovered that a closed but highly-upvoted question with highly-upvoted answers has been deleted by the community.

What do you do now, if anything?

Comment: Did you have a particular example in mind? Asking since I imagine the possible responses would depend on the question's topic (for instance, joke post vs. old shopping question vs. something else).

Comment: @whrrgarbl Those are points I hope a candidate would cover in their answer. I'm more interested in the thought process, rather than a specific decision on a specific question.

Comment: I think the most important question would be "why would you do anything"

Comment: Such questions are sometimes restored by a moderator and given a [historical lock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266418/what-makes-a-question-historically-significant) status.

Answer (score 11):

How would you handle a high-rep (10k+) user who tends to get into "flame wars"/heated discussions with others and/or frequently has comments flagged as rude or offensive? Would it make any difference if they were extremely high reputation users (e.g. 50k or 100k)? In general, would you tend to be more "gentle" moderating content from high-rep users?

Answer (score 9):

What (if anything) do you think should be done about the fact that there are so many items in the close vote queue? Do you support lowering the number of close votes required to close questions? To what extent (if any) should moderators actively work the close vote queue?

Comment: This is in my opinion one of the most important questions of them all. I've practically given up flagging questions for closure since most of my should be closed flags age away. I feel strongly that something needs to be done about this issue. See also [my Meta question about this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349542/4284627).

Comment: @DonaldDuck I agree with you (and with the Meta post). I have a [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) arguing for reducing the number of votes required to close questions.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Please refer to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/352281#comment491009_351972) - The answers in this post are not meant to get examples and personal feedback by the community, they are for the future moderators. I don't say that your opinions are not important but please consider removing them from answers (As I also did too BTW)

Comment: @AlonEton I'm not sure that DonaldDuck was supplying his own answer *per se* so much as explaining why he thinks that future moderators why he thinks that future moderators should address the issue. (I personally think that it's a major issue facing the community and that more needs to be done to address it, and that that's something that future moderators could at least influence).

Comment: @EJoshuaS NP. I just think that if this is so important topic (I too supported your suggestion to reduce the votes to 4), then it will be reflected by the votes. Then, if a candidate will relate to your question then you could vote for them in the elections. But anyway - Point taken :)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not as relevant as recent events have dictated, but I like [my previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337199/1079354) from last year.

Not everyone here ventures into the chat rooms, and not many people know what goes on there. However, as a moderator, one of your duties involves the moderation of the chat rooms. If you've never been in a chat room before and you were called to resolve an issue with either the room or its users, what would be the first thing you would do?

Note: "thing" isn't limited to moderator action in this context.

Answer (score 8):

You stumble upon a question with a few downvotes. You see the user is new here, and has asked an extremely basic question that any self respecting programmer (including you), would find, perhaps a little ridiculous (say, a syntax error or a misunderstanding of how a basic programming construct works). You aren't the only one with this thought. A group of users have commented the same voicing their opinion, being passive aggressive and borderline condescending in the comments.

You think about closing the question, but it is indeed on topic, ridiculous as it may be, and is not a candidate for closure.

You see more users taking a cue and ganging up on OP. What would your next, immediate course of action be?

Comment: Would this include dupes as well or does `not a candidate for closure` mean that the question would not be a dupe?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I believe it would be something really basic like using an except statement without a try (in python), for which you don't really have a duplicate (or maybe you do, but for my example, no).

Answer (score 7):

Split off from Grace Note's generic-questions answer, because I feel it gets at the motivations of the candidate:

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: What's the point of just repeating Grace's question? You want them to answer it twice?

Comment: @TylerH, her question states: they're only used "if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8)."

Comment: @whrrgarbl Thanks, I didn't see that part. Seems like they should just include all of them by default though if they get asked often enough to be considered for that post, and if they're questions the CM team wants answers to...

Answer (score 6):

What is your general assessment and opinion of groups who *en masse* take any kind of voting action against content in an organized fashion?  If such a group is a problem, what would you do to mitigate it?

Comment: Is it worth it to make a difference in the question between up/down voting (which involves rep) and close/reopen delete/undelete voting (moderation), or do you like them in the same bucket?

Comment: This question would benefit from the caveat that some employees (namely, Shog) have given their blessing to some such groups (namely, the group that likely inspired this question).

Comment: @TylerH:  It'd be interesting to see that, honestly.  A tacit blessing is *slightly* different than actual policy approval, though.

Comment: @Makoto https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256508/2756409

Comment: @TylerH:  So it seems my question still remains relatively valid. Having an opinion of them is important especially if it runs counter to tacitly approved convention, and knowing what to do if they step outside of the guidelines is something I would expect moderators to do.

Comment: @Makoto Sure, I never said it was an invalid question; I just wanted to make sure candidates don't feel like it's a loaded question.

Comment: Is this specifically asking about the close vote chatroom?

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  Doesn't have to be a chatroom on site, now does it?  Could be off-site.  SOCVR is one we know of that's on site, and while that does have tacit approval, it doesn't mean that there may not be problems caused by the group's actions.  My recommendation would be not to interpret this as solely about SOCVR, as while I have my issues with it, it's not the *only* way people can organize and vote on questions/answers, and mods should be prepped to deal with it.

Answer (score 4):

Often, in my excursions into the VLQ (very low quality) review, I find answers that have been flagged that consist only of a code-block.

Are these answers low quality? Should they be flagged? How would you handle these cases?

Comment: Note that some of those (very short) answers are auto-flagged by the system, not by users.

Answer (score 2):

When do you find yourself having to take a decision for which the community doesn't reach "consensus", how do you solve the impasse?

Would you do nothing, since there isn't consensus? Would you consult with others more knowledgeable about the issue? Flip a coin and hope for the best?

Comment: "Would you consult with others more knowledgeable about the issue" - also, _who_ would the candidate consult with? How would they determine who could provide unbiased knowledge? That seems relevant to me.

Comment: @S.L.Barth is my very biased view that the stuff community seems to not be able to reach consensus is usually of technical nature. So, I believe that having technical expertise would be a qualifier.

Comment: As in [The Community vs the Domain Expert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/812149), I suppose? You have raised your concerns about over-zealous edit rejections, more than once.

Comment: @S.L.Barth not only that, also closures/deletions, naa's, etc. The expert is mostly ignored on those issues. I recall Shog himself saying that if you don't know about something, you shouldn't be moderating that something (or something in the same vein).

Answer (score 2):

As we communicate & interact with new users every time, here's a question which I considered interesting from [2 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289517/6378815) (with some edits):

> A new user arguing with one or more experienced user(s) over
>   disagreement against a question closure with certain reasons, and then
>   starting complains to the community that this site is "unfriendly to newcomers". How do
>   you respond properly to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever disagreed with administrative action taken against you (or another user) on SO? How would you, as a moderator, handle things differently?

Comment: I thought about a question like this, but if someone has never had administrative action taken against them, their answer won't be very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : 
What is your take on correct yet witty answers?

Long Version:
Of the many kinds of ways of answering a question, here are two:

> 1. Highly Technical.
> 2. Technical and containing humour.

Given a situation where an answer in the style of 2 was down-voted and flagged by certain veteran users for being "ineffective", "misleading", "chatty" or "ambiguous", but your review of the answer does not say so, 
how would you respond to the situation?

In case any action that was taken from yours or the community's end, that resulted in decreasing the views of the answer, and this action was met with criticism from the poster or some of the users who upvoted it, how would you handle it?

PS: Apologies if this wasn't clear. Feel free to post a comment seeking clarification, or if you're feeling like you understood the point, please edit it. Cheers! :)

Comment: Are you talking about answers or comments?

Comment: Thank you for seeking clarification. I was referring to answers that have humour in them, either in the explanation or in the example. The gist is, if humour was claimed by some to "affect the quality" of an answer, while others think it important for understanding, what ought to be the moderator's stance on the matter?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I won't reply with my opinion of course because this question is for the candidates to answer

Answer (score -1):

Moderators sometimes have to deal with conflict in an objective, professional manner. Sometimes, these conflicts will be about issues you have a strong opinion one way or another about.

A conversation emerges on Meta about the topicality of a post. You feel very strongly it should remain open, yet it has been closed. A tag expert argues that the question does not fit the rules and should most definitely be closed and even deleted.

How do you handle the situation? What if the question is deleted in the course of the discussion? How would your answer change if the disagreeing party was a normal high-rep user rather than a tag expert, if at all?

Answer (score -7):

There is an old problem on the site, the tremendous size of the VtC queue. Do you have any idea, how could you help on it as moderator? Is it actually a problem?

Answer (score -9):

A new user asked a question, which was later dupe-hammered by a high-rep user. The new user, via the comments, made a case as to why their question was not a duplicate. You saw that the comment by the high-rep user stating why it was a duplicate had 6 upvotes, but you believe that **it wasn't** a duplicate. Do you re-open it immediately? And if not, what do you do?

Comment: I would also say that this is more down to the community not a moderator. The OP _can_ take their question to meta should they want to.

Comment: @JohnMiliter The downvotes are from people (Including myself) that (I assume) believe that your question is irrelevant, since a moderator will unlikely reopen your question - One should edit their post, explain why their question is not duplicate,  and then the community will decide if to reopen it or not, so this is up to the community to decide (by votes) and less a moderator thing. This is not personal BTW

Comment: Also I think, most mods don't do anything in such a case. But, asking this question from the candidates would be useful, to make their view clear.

Comment: @JohnMiliter Downvotes don't mean the same thing on Meta as on the main site. Votes on Meta mean that users agree or disagree with the post. There is nothing wrong with your answer, it's just that a lot of people disagree with it. In this case, they don't think this is a good question to ask the candidates.

Answer (score -9):

A user complains that they are a target of [stealth serial downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308502/812149). Looking at the user's reputation history, there is indeed a dubious pattern. You see a similar pattern in your moderator tools.

However, you cannot see who downvoted.

How would you determine if the user was indeed the target of stealth serial voting, or just has a number of posts that raise controversy? At what point would you escalate to Stack Overflow employees (who, unlike moderators, *can* see who downvoted)?

Comment: This question is a bit unfair to users that are not moderators elsewhere. They aren't aware of what tools *do* exist that can be used to help this investigation.

Comment: @Andy These tools aren't secret, are they? People who aren't moderators (yet) can find out. Then they'll also have a better idea what they're getting into.

Answer (score -11):

When a question/ answer on a topic you are **not** well-versed in is flagged, what would you do and why?

Comment: Are  you implying moderators should only moderate languages that they're familiar with?

Comment: @Cerbrus no, it wasn't about language, more regarding a tool or technique.

Comment: Same difference: are you implying moderators that aren't familiar with AngularJS can't moderate AngularJS questions?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it depends on the case. For example, to decide if a comment is insulting or not, can be done with zero technical knowledge. To decide, that a question is dupe or not, requires high skills in the area. Asking from the candidates their views in this matter, I think it is useful - I can't agree this so many downs.

Comment: Dupe votes aren't really a moderator's responsibility, though.

Comment: People can post intelligent sounding nonsense, just to troll. And some languages, like Haskell, can look like total gibberish if you're not familiar with them. The dilemma does exist - how do you determine if the post is trolling or just out of your knowledge?

Answer (score -15):

The community migrations are quite hard on the SO. The requirements:

- only 5 target sites are allowed
- at least 4 of the 5 close votes should vote to migration, and to the same site
- question older as 2 months can't be migrated any more
- at least one of the tags should exist also on the target site

This can result that a question is closed despite that it could have been answered on different sites.

Others think that questions should be migrated only rarely, for example by making this whole thing moderator-only.

What do you think about it?

1. Should it be made even more hard?
2. Is it okay?
3. Or it should be more easy?

In the case of (1) or (3), how would your actions try to move the things into this direction?

Comment: This is a discussion question you should ask on Meta, not something that should be asked of each moderator candidate. These rules aren't even something that moderators have control over!

Comment: @CodyGray Although the mods are bound strongly by the rules of the SE and the community consent, they have a highly above average influence to both. They have also a significant freedom, how do they apply the rules to individual cases. Seeing your reputation and meta history, I can't believe that *I* have to explain this to *you*. I find it surreal.

Comment: Regardless of the opinions of an individual moderator, the enumerated are hard limitations of the system that they *cannot* bypass. They have absolutely no freedom here; such is precisely the point. They would have to campaign the SE staff to change the system, and the appropriate place to do that is here on Meta. Empirical evidence also refutes that moderators have any stronger sway over the SE staff when it comes to feature requests and/or rule changes than do other members of the community in good standing. Recently, *nothing* has managed to persuade SE staff to update the Q&A engine.

Comment: @CodyGray That is not the case, mods have a relative high level of freedom. The *reason* of their extra powers is that both the SE and the community believes, they can be trusted with it. Furthermore, knowing the opinion of a moderator in a critical question is important, it is an essential part of the decision about the election votes. Furthermore, I think in a healthy community, the views of the mods reflect the views of the community, thus the views of the mods are important.

Comment: None of the moderator powers have anything to do with what you're talking about.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, now that your reaction was simply repeating your previous arguments, I think here is the end of this thread. Have a nicer day!

Answer (score -20):

Question re-posted from [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337266/6206720):

> A user vandalises their post and enters a "rollback war", trying to change it to simply read "QUESTION REMUVED FOR PRIVACY". They had also submitted (rejected) suggested edits to do likewise to the answers.
>
> By the time you see it they've also flagged or commented on the question:
>
> ```
> Please delete this ASAP, it's super urgent that I remove this because my 
> university honor code demands that I do and I'm going to get kicked out
> ```
>
> The question was pretty poor to begin with, but received 3 decent answers and had been edited a little before the vandalism started.
>
> What do you do?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of Brad's question?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351982/2415822

Answer (score -30):

How do we encourage and enforce the rule of being nice? Too often, good questions deemed too simple are downvoted and ridiculed or, worse, downvoted without reason. This could likely be slightly addressed by forcing people to consider their voting habits a little more closely...

Secondary question:

- Would you support necessitating a comment explaining a downvote before downvoting is allowed?

  - This is similar to [this META post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/4581200)
  - Your explanation (more than your response) is what matters here).

Comment: _"downvoted without reason"_: That's a matter of perspective.

Comment: consider giving a read to [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/839601) and 36 questions [linked to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/250177?lq=1)

Comment: Moderators have no influence on site features, so whether a moderator supports necessitating downvote comments is not really of importance (although it would put them on my personal "never vote for this person ever" list). Apart from deleting outright rude and offensive content, moderators also have little influence on the site's tone.

Comment: ["Be Nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) doesn't mean that I have to go out of my way to wipe your arse, it means that I shouldn't be mean and nasty. Often times this means _not_ leaving a comment, because it's easier to be nice by saying nothing at all, than to explain why this question is the worst question I've seen all day in a nice way.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Although mods have no influence on site features, they have a special contact with the SE and with the community. There are continously complaints about the problem of the unexplained massive downs, thus I think it is useful to ask from the mod candidates their views about this.

Comment: @peterh but why, exactly? How are their views on voting supposed to inform their behaviour as moderators? They can't cancel out other people's votes (thank goodness), they can't force downvoters to leave a comment, and they can't do anything in response to people complaining about unexplained downvotes. They can't even very well remove every comment that isn't totally super nice, because you'd remove a lot of useful info in the process. What should they do differently depending on what their position on this is?

Comment: @Pekka웃 If it is [stealth serial downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308502/812149), that is something mods could perhaps see. I'm aware they don't see actual voting, but they can see voting patterns, right? So a more refined question is, "at what point do you think a voting pattern is stealth voting, and what actions would you take to stop it?"

Comment: @S.L.Barth all true, but individual users targeting other users is not what we are talking about here. The complaint here is "voting culture on SO is such that established users will downvote questions, often from new users, that don't conform to the site's very complex and (from the outside) arbitrary-looking rules, but will not leave an explanation telling the OP how they can improve. That's mean and there should be a feature forcing those users to provide feedback on how the question can be improved when downvoting."

Comment: @Pekka웃 Point well made. I was just checking if the issue of stealth serial voting has already been mentioned in a candidate question. It seems not, so I'll make that candidate question myself. (And the ambiguity of the term "candidate question" here is deliberate :-) )

Comment: @Pekka웃 Although mods are strongly bound by the SE rules and by the community consent, they have a highly above average influence to both. They have also a significant freedom in applying these rules to induvidual cases. Knowing the view of a mod about a for me critical question, it can affect my election vote, despite that they can't directly cause revolutionary changes (or to stop/avoid ongoing changes). Honestly, seeing your reputation and large meta history, I am simply surprised why I have to explain this to you.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think nearly all downvotes *have* a reason, the real question is, why it isn't communicated. And the obvious answer is that *communicating it* would break the site rules And this is why this question is, yes, and important and useful one. Knowing the opinion of a candidate about this *can* affect the election votes.

Comment: Downvote reasons aren't communicated because it's noise. Most of the times I comment about why I downvote something, it ends in an argument. Hardly any user can take criticism like that. Mandatory downvote reasons will just guarantee gibberish to be entered. The suggestion is made ridiculously often, always by users that don't do any research. If a candidate answers "yes" to this, the candidate should immediately be removed, as they're obviously woefully unaware of how SO works.

Comment: @peterh `they have also a significant freedom in applying these rules to induvidual cases.` that's all very accurate... *when it's about things that actually have to do with moderation,* like "I think we are too hard on new users and closing their questions too early." *That* is actually something that is relevant, because as mods they get to make decisions on whether to close a question or not, and their stance is a hint at how strictly or leniently they will interpret community policy.

Comment: But I still don't see why a candidate's opinion on an unpopular feature request that looks good at first glance but would be awful when you think it through (which is why the community almost unanimously rejects it) is of any more consequence than their opinion on any other feature request on Meta. Except that supporting that particular request would make them look really, really dumb  in my book.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, furthermore prescribing a reasoning to the downs would weaken them to irrelevant. *But OMG, this answer is not about that we want this is feature or not! This answer is about that we want to ask the mod candidates about it, or not!* And I am sure, the current voting score of this answer is because the majority of the downvoters are simply *incapable* to make this distinction! They've just voted it down!

Comment: @peterh I agree this post would probably have worked great without its second half. Maybe someone should post it again with just that.

Comment: @peterh exactly, this question is relevant to understand a candidate's philosophy/opinion about these topics: not nice attitudes, voting patterns, commenting/not commenting when providing down votes, etc.. It's supposed to help us understand how a candidate thinks and responds. Clearly some people are too closed minded to see beyond their own stubborn, haughty approaches to this site and it's folks like that that I would never vote to help moderate.

Comment: @Cerbrus look, I get not wanting to comment to new users b/c often times they ask really bad questions and will just fight about it because they don't understand the rules/norms here. BUT, unexplained downvoting and lack of constructive commenting is often absent even amongst users who have been around for years with hundreds/thousands of experience. I've had countless questions downvoted without explanation even though they follow the rules/norms of the site and effectively comply with "how to write a good question"....

Comment: ...Lack of research effort is a BS reason, b/c I can guarantee I spend half my life on this site, or on google or toying around with code because literally anything is better and less stressful than throwing yourself to the wolves that linger on SO ready to downvote you because they are better than you or know more than you. "That answer is so obvious to me" is a terrible reason to downvote, especially if left unexplained. At least provide the 5 word answer!

Comment: Also, as for commenting, I've seen mods and high rep users even *close* questions without providing a reason and worse, I've seen instances where users use their "power" to close questions with invalid reasons and, once demonstrated that theyve done so, will sit there and find other reasons until one fits well enough. That's called a power trip, and its inappropriate from top users that should be model users. Answering questions like the one proposed here will help determine what kinds of attitudes and hopefully philosophies candidates have towards practices similar to these.

Comment: What's sad is that people are voting to *delete* this post! It's META, people! You don't delete a post b/c you disagree with it - you downvote. Oy!!

Comment: Agreed. So far it's just one person though.

Comment: `"That answer is so obvious to me" is a terrible reason to downvote, especially if left unexplained. At least provide the 5 word answer!` OK. But what does any of this have to do with the upcoming moderator elections? Honestly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Personal philosophy. If a candidate doesn't see anything wrong with those practices (i.e., not being a model user here) then I likely am not interested in voting for them regardless of how well they could mod. There is an unhealthy attitude/atmosphere here at SO and feeding the fire with more of the same is not something I'm interested in doing.

Comment: A moderator's stance on that dumb feature request says nothing about what attitude among users they favour or are likely to encourage, or what their moderation style is likely to be. You are conflating things that have nothing to do with one another here. Take away that thing with the feature request and this is a decent question to ask a candidate.

Comment: Opposition is one thing. Their explanation is another. It's the explanation and where they could go with that discussion that is valuable. Also, other SE sites require or at least encourage that downvotes and close votes be accompanied by comments -- it's not like it *couldn't* be the way this site works. It's just not the way that the current bunch of high rep programmers function. Again, why keep providing roles of prominence to people that share the same philosophy?

Comment: @Pekka웃 fine I will edit the question to have an optional secondary question about the "feature request" (though it's not a feature, it's a behavior). I look forward to your upvote following the update.