# Do SE moderators have a specified code of conduct?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Do SE moderators have a code of conduct like e.g. [the contributor covenant](http://contributor-covenant.org/version/1/4/)?

If not, should SE moderators here have a similar approach?

Comment: Did you mean to post this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351972/3001761)? Then why did you ask it as a new question?

Comment: Your comment starts with "no", then suggests you actually mean "yes". If this is a proposed question for would-be moderators in the upcoming election, post it *as an answer* at the link above: *"Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer."*.

Comment: Don't sweat downvotes on Meta; they are applied liberally for all sorts of reasons. You won't lose any reputation from them.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how well this would work as an answer to that Q&A thread, though - Stack Exchange arguably has a very robust moderation philosophy and I don't see what new value a third party contributor covenant would bring to the table. If there's something missing from SE's guidance then that might be worth talking about, but I don't think that's an argument that's being made here, is it?

Answer (score 9):

There's a huge body of work on moderation on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, and [an agreement new moderators have to sign.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

Most, if not all, of the points covered by the document you link to are covered by SO's theory of moderation, either explicitly or implicitly. I'd say it's fair to say that yes, they do have a similar approach.

See also:

- [A theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)
- [Stack Exchange moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq)

Answer (score 7):

The Stack Exchange code of conduct can be found in the help center as "Be Nice" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). It's not explicitly called a code of conduct, but it's essentially the same thing.

> #### Be Nice.
>
> Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share what you know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together.  Be
>   welcoming and patient, *especially* with those who may not know everything you do.  Oh, and bring your
>   sense of humor. Just in case.
>
> That basically covers it. But these three guidelines may help:
>
> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.**  Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*
> 2. **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to *demands* for help.
> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, [flag](/help/flagging) them:
>
>    - **Name-calling.** Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when
>        they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
>    - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate
>        individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation,
>        religion, etc. will not be tolerated.  At all.  (Those are *just a few examples*; when in doubt, just don't.)
>    - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is *not* a dating site.
>    - **Harassment and
>        bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, [flag](/help/flagging) it. 
>        If it keeps up, *disengage* — we'll handle it. If something needs *staff* attention, you can use the [contact us](/contact) link at the bottom of every page.
>
> We're proud to be a large, user-driven space on the internet where name-calling, harassment, and other
>   online nastiness are almost non-existent. It's up to all of us to keep it that way.
>
> **In summary, have fun, and be good to each other.**

These rules apply to all users, including moderators. There are only a few additional rules for moderators like the Moderator agreement Pekka mentioned.

Comment: Good point. I was looking for this (much more on point than the mod agreement) and somehow didn't find it!